# The type or namespace name 'Size' could not be found

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, xna

I always get this error message in the following line:

```
static private Size size;
```

> The type or namespace name 'Size' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

What is wrong?

Comment: You're not using whatever namespace or assembly contains the definition for the class Size.  Or you haven't defined it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure the following `using` directive is at the top of your file/class/page:

```
using Windows.Foundation;
```

That's the namespace where the [`Size` struct](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.foundation.size) is defined.

Answer (score 1):

you have specified that the variable size is of type Size, and the compiler is telling you it doesn't know where the code that defines the class called "Size" is located. Have you created another class called Size, or is there an assembly you are trying to use that has the class Size in it?

Answer (score 0):

Somewhere in your code you need to define

```
package myObjects;

public class Size {
    public Size(){
        //constructor
    }
 }
```

After importing this namespace, you will be able to declare an object of this type.

```
import myObjects;
```